# How can I unlock different products with the same IAP product id?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm creating a ReactNative app that allows uses to unlock various classes, same price for every class.

How can I handle this while respecting Apple's IAP Policy?

More specific questions:

1) If I were to use a `consumable` product, won't that get my app rejected ?? It would work technically, I can have the class id in the purchase reference field

2) If I were to use `non-consumable` products, is there some way to update them server-to-server ? or just the classic method for manual bulk updating

I know the easy option will be to introduce some `in-app currency` that you can buy with a `consumable`, but I would really want to avoid that.

Regards,
Gabriel